# automating windows executable selecting drop down elements, clicking buttons

Tags: python, windows, installation, automation, executable

I'm interested in automating some windows application: particularly if I have to execute the app, select elements from a dropdown and following an installation (for example).
Suppose for example I would launch and control a series of installation of different applications after a reimage
I want to do this in Python but I'm open to other languages if they offer better chances to do this.
anyone can point to a  python library I could use to accomplish that?

Comment: It's not python but autohotkey is designed to do this type of task well.

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/AutoHotkey.py/ might work.

It's actually just a wrapper around autohotkey.